# What is the Population size implied by a known Finite Distribution of objects?

Tags: combinatorics

I believe this falls in the category of enumerative combinatorics.

I would like to calculate the population size implied by finite distributions of up to c = 75 objects. Here's a few examples:

{75};
{1,1,1,...,1} (75 1's);
{1,4,5,11,54};
{2,6,7,60}

The first contains 75 copies of the same object. There are 75 objects and thus the population size of all possibilities is 75.

The second contains 1 copy of all the 75 objects. There are 75! unique orderings of this.

The remainder are nontrivial. Having worked a few smaller examples (c = 4 to 6), I arrived at this possibly incorrect formula:

Let
c = # of objects
s = length of frequency list,
f[i] = the ith frequency with i=0 to s-1,
(n, k) = binomial coefficient.

p = Product[(c-i, f[i])((c-i)/f[i]); i=0 to s-1]

Corrections?

Comment: It would be clearer if you took a smaller example such as $4$ which you can write as $4$ or $3+1$ or $2+2$ or $2+1+1$ or $1+1+1+1$.  How many times do you want to count each of these types of partition?

Comment: Combinations involve products, not sums.

Comment: Read my question as how many of each of $(4), (3,1), (2,2), (2,1,1), (1,1,1,1)$  covering all possibilities.  They each add up to $4$ in the same way as your examples added up to $75$.

Comment: Frequencies must be stated in non decreasing order. I am using brackets to avoid confusion with binomial notation. I read your question as {4}, {1,3}, {2,2}, {1,1,2}, {1,1,1,1}. In each case we are choosing from 4 objects with possible replication. For example, an instance of {1,3} is the ordered set {a,b,b,b}.

Comment: Can you tell me the number of cases for each pattern and so the total with $4$ objects? Even the number of instances with $\{1,3\}$ would be a start. Is it $12$?  Otherwise it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: There are 48 instances of {1,3}:
{a,a,a,b},{a,a,a,c},{a,a,a,d},{a,a,b,a},{a,a,c,a},{a,a,d,a},{a,b,a,a},{a,b,b,b},{a,c,a,a},{a,c,c,c},{a,d,a,a},{a,d,d,d},{b,a,a,a},{b,a,b,b},{b,b,a,b},{b,b,b,a},{b,b,b,c},{b,b,b,d},{b,b,c,b},{b,b,d,b},{b,c,b,b},{b,c,c,c},{b,d,b,b},{b,d,d,d},{c,a,a,a},{c,a,c,c},{c,b,b,b},{c,b,c,c},{c,c,a,c},{c,c,b,c},{c,c,c,a},{c,c,c,b},{c,c,c,d},{c,c,d,c},{c,d,c,c},{c,d,d,d},{d,a,a,a},{d,a,d,d},{d,b,b,b},{d,b,d,d},{d,c,c,c},{d,c,d,d},{d,d,a,d},{d,d,b,d},{d,d,c,d},{d,d,d,a},{d,d,d,b},{d,d,d,c}

Comment: OK - that is helpful and makes the answer much easier.  With $4$, the total number of possibilities is $4^4=256$

Comment: With 4, the population of the distribution {1,1,1,1} is 4!. As shown in the comment above, the population of the distribution {1,3} is 48.

Comment: Yes, so $4$ for $\{4\}$, and $48$ for $\{1,3\}$, and $36$ for $\{2,2\}$, and  $144$ for $\{1,1,2\}$, and  $24$ for $\{1,1,1,1\}$.  Then $4+48+36+144+24 = 256=4^4$

Answer (score 1):

With $75$ possible types of objects put in $75$ ordered positions, the total number of possibilities is $$75^{75} \approx 4 \times 10^{140}$$ since each of the $75$ positions can have any of the $75$ types of objects independently of the types of objects in the other positions.

---

If you want the number of cases for a particular partition of $n$ (what you call a distribution) into $n$ non-negative parts including zeros, where the parts sized $k$ appear $n_k$ times and so $\sum\limits_k n_k =n$ and $\sum\limits_k n_k k = n$ too, then the number is $$\frac{n!}{\prod\limits_k (n_k!)} \times \frac{n!}{\prod\limits_k (k!)^{n_k}}$$
and if  you add these up across all the possible partitions of $n$ then you get $n^n$.

As an example, if $n=75$ and you take the partition with $75$ ones $($i.e. $n_1=75$ and all the other $n_k=0)$ then this gives $\frac{75!}{75!}\times \frac{75!}{(1!)^{75}}=75!$ as you expect. Similarly if you take the partition just with one $75$ (so implicitly $74$ zeros) you use  $n_{75}=1$ and $n_0=74$ to get $\frac{75!}{74!1!}\times \frac{75!}{(0!)^{74}(75!)^1}=75$ again as you expect.

It is perhaps easier to illustrate with the partitions of $n=4$

$$\begin{array}
& 1,1,1,1: & n_1=4 : & \frac{4!}{4!}\times \frac{4!}{(1!)^{4}} & =24 \\
 1,1,2(,0): & n_0=1,n_1=2,n_2=1  : & \frac{4!}{1!2!1!}\times \frac{4!}{(0!)^1(1!)^{2}(2!)^{1}} & =144 \\
 2,2(,0,0): & n_0=2,n_2=2  : & \frac{4!}{2!2!}\times \frac{4!}{(0!)^2(2!)^{2}} & =36 \\
 1,3(,0,0): & n_0=2,n_1=1,n_3=1  : & \frac{4!}{2!1!1!}\times \frac{4!}{(0!)^2(1!)^{1}(3!)^{1}} & =48 \\
 4(,0,0,0): & n_0=3,n_4=1  : & \frac{4!}{3!1!}\times \frac{4!}{(0!)^3(4!)^{1}} & =4 \\
\end{array}$$

and note $24+144+36+48+4=256=4^4$.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Instead, the population of the trivial distribution {1,1,1,...,1} (75 1's) is 75!. Note that the values in the distributions are frequencies. How would you compute the population of {2,6,7,60} ?

Comment: $75! \ll 75^{75}$ so there is no problem there.  For your $\{2,6,7,60\}$ there would be $\frac{75!}{1!1!1!1!71!}\times \frac{75!}{2!6!7!60!}$ possibilities.  But there are $8118264$ partitions of $75$ and you do not want to do this sort of calculation for each partition

Comment: I am saying if you do the calculation for each of the 8 million plus distributions (what I call partitions) and then add the numbers up, you end up with a total of $75^{75}$

Comment: I am interested in subsets of the general population with specific distributions. You're correct that I'm not interested in all partitions of c objects (c=75 at the moment). But I am typically interested in a few dozen at a time and thus I would like a formula for doing so. Thank you for the calculation of {2,6,7,60}. What is the formula (my original question) for distribution {f1,...,fs} of c objects?

Comment: @Hermitian I have added my expression for the calculation for a particular partition/distribution which I hope helps

Comment: I am very grateful for your patience and extended effort in answering my query. I have implemented this formula and it matches empirical values for small values of n. Thanks!